# Отправка E-mail с сайта

Tags: html, email, javascript

Имеется сайт на Народ.ru. На сайте есть страничка Заказы, где производиться заказ услуг по выполнению работы. Есть форма для заполнения заказа (поля - email - кто заказал, name - тема заказа, zakaz - сам текст заказа, что нужно). Нужно реализовать содержимое заполненных форм по Email.

Я перепробовал кучу скриптов, но ничего не вышло... Яндекс открывает страницу создания нового письма, и в строку "Кому", вставляет всю введенную ранее в форму информацию... Хотя по идее, по нажатию кнопки отправить должна открыться почтовая программа пользователя и  поля письма "Кому", "Тема", "Сообщение", должны быть автоматически заполнены данными...

Как это реализовать на самом деле? Т.е. правильно) Спасибо.

```
<FORM NAME="mailer" METHOD="post" ENCTYPE="text/plain"
onSubmit="(document.mailer.action += mailtoandSubject)">
Email:<br>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="email" size="24"
onChange="msg (this.form)"><br>
Тема или название работы:<br>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="Subject" size="24"
onChange="msg (this.form)"><br>
Текст задания:<br>
<TEXTAREA NAME="zadanie" COLS="40" ROWS="6"
onChange="msg (this.form)">
</TEXTAREA>
<br>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Отправить"
ONCLICK="return checkIt ()">
<INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Сброс">
</FORM>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function checkIt () {
    if (document.forms.mailer.email.value!= "") {
    } else {
        alert ("Пожалуйста, введите свой Email.");
        document.forms.mailer.email.focus ();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.forms.mailer.Subject.value!= "") {
    } else {
        alert ("Пожалуйста, введите название или тему работы:");
        document.forms.mailer.Subject.focus ();
        return false;
    }
    if (document.forms.mailer.zadanie.value!= "") {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert ("Пожалуйста, напишите задание работы.");
        document.forms.mailer.zadanie.focus ();
        return false;
    }
}

function msg () {
    document.mailer.action = "mailto:Leshij-2005@yandex.ru"
    mailtoandSubject = (('?Subject=' + document.mailer.Subject.value) + '&Body=' + document.mailer.zadanie.value);
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Что здесь не так?...

Comment: А на народе php разве поддерживается??

Comment: Народ нет... Тока Js... Блин эт что получается все дело в методе POST?

Comment: А для mailto: не нужен php) это вызов функции на клиенте. обрабатывается например outlook'ом.

Comment: @Leshij_2005 дело не в методе POST, а в том, что на вашем компе для обработки ссылок mailto: установлена яндекс.почта. У других пользователей все будет работать =) И вам бы советовал поставить клиент почтовый, но это дело вкуса. Будет много писем - оцените)

Comment: @Sh4dow, спасибо, все понятно) А у каких других пользователей?... И можно как то принудительно назначить клиента, к примеру если пользователь ввел поле Email, то мы проверяем домен, и открываем для него соответствующий клиент(для Яндекса - mail.yandex.ru, для Mail - win.mail.ru, и т.д), возможно ли такое?..

Comment: @Leshij_2005 для этого вам нужно будет вручную формировать URL для каждого email-сервиса, который вы хотите поддерживать (попробуйте проанализировать адресные строки, когда составляете письма в них или погуглите на этот счет). Но этот способ а) чреват ошибками (на хешкоде как-то был вопрос с GMail и "Стандартным видом", не помню, решили ли его), б) является навязчивым для пользователя. Использование mailto:, на мой взгляд, является принятым стандартом.

Comment: Вот эт я и имел ввиду - ручное форматирование) Ну я не думаю что такой способ будет навязчивым, прост так удобней будет, заполнить форму и вызвать почтовый клиент..Чем сначала вызвать почтовый клиент, а потом по образцу заполнять содержимое письма-заказа... Так придется пользователю согласится с предлагаемыми сервисами, причем зависят они от его Email...
@yozh, а не знаете какие id  у почтовых форм Яндекса, Mail, Google... Прост когда я попробовал перенаправить на Mail, то В Кому записался Email куда отправить, а все остальное записалось в Сообщение...

Comment: @Leshij_2005 Вам тут все верно говорят. Если ваш клиент - это ваш выбор, то я как пользователь обижусь на то, что с моим admin[цабака]sh4dow.ru меня послали далеко и надолго) И у меня нет веб-интерфейса в почте) mailto: и придуман для того, чтоб пользователю было удобнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень много лишнего.

Уберите onsubmit.
onChange="msg(this.form)" можно заменить на onChange="msg()".
Переменная mailtoandSubject у вас не объявлена как глобальная. Имхо, она вообще не нужна. Проставьте id (Форма: id="mailer", Subject: id="mailer-subject", zadanie: id="mailer-zadanie")

```
function msg () {
  document.getElementById('mailer').action = 
    "mailto:Leshij-2005@yandex.ru"
    + '?Subject=' + document.getElementById('mailer-subject').value
    + '&Body=' + document.getElementById('mailer-zadanie').value;
  return false;
  }
```

**UPD**: вот вам 100% рабочий код) Адаптируете, надеюсь - только id заменить

```
<html><head></head><body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function msg1() {
    document.getElementById('f1').action = 'mailto:Leshij-2005@yandex.ru' + '?subject='+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('i1').value) + '&body='+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('i2').value);
    alert(document.getElementById('f1').action);
    return false;
    }
</script>
<form method="post" action="" id="f1">
<input id="i1" onchange="msg1()" value="" />
<input id="i2" onchange="msg1()" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="ok" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

ЗЫ: 'Subject' != 'subject', 'Body' != 'body'

Comment: Попробовал через id, но результат тот же... Все в одной строке "Кому"...

Comment: Смотрите обновление

Comment: Увы но то же самое) Вся инфа в одной строчке "Кому".. Скорее всего здесь дело в самой системе Яндекса..

Comment: Яндекса? хммм, вы, похоже, ее по дефолту для обработки указали)) Этого лучше не делать. Я не знаю, какая кодировка на народе, но подозреваю ср1251, скорее всего, это глюк передачи в юникодную яндекс.почты. Outlook/Firebird принимает без проблем.

Comment: @Sh4dow, а вы уверены что при mailto все будет работать нормально?? как показывает мой пример, где у меня по умолчанию почтовый клиент эт Яндекс, ничего не работает.. А я не один такой.. Так что эт тоже надо учесть...

Comment: Вообще понимаете в чем дело... Обработка ошибок пользователя - это первое зло, от которого надо отказаться. Это почтовый клиент должен правильно принимать ссылки mailto: а не программист _правильное_ написание изменять на неправильное в связи с нерабочестью ПО пользователя. Т.е. если почтовый клиент не справляется с парсингом протокола, менять нужно его, а не протокол. А из-за подхода, от которого вы имеете шанс отказаться, у нас 20% юзеров сидят на IE<9, а программисты тратят драгоценное время на обход их багов. <pre></pre>У меня в Опере по дефолту стоит Outlook, а я его удалил. Учтете? =)

Answer (score 0):

В итоге, легче и удобней всего, как мне кажется, эт написать программу для клиента чтоб проделывать заказ работ, и на сайте ссылочку для скачивания и подробное описание... И все будет сразу хорошо, т.е. все будет ссылаться в одно место и информация будет иметь правильный вид... Иначе же переходить на "хороший" хост и там уже всеми доступными средствами творить...

Comment: Экзешник никто качать не будет. Хостинг с PHP можно найти за полтинник в месяц. (А если вас не смущает репутация narod.ru, то и бесплатные есть). Готовых скриптов обратной связи - туева хуча) Я не понимаю, зачем вам столько гемора, занимался вообще этим вопросом только из спортивного интереса)

Comment: Да просто мне моя обратная связь нужна, с моими полями ввода, там их по задумке около 7.. А потом после ввода их форматировать и отправлять на email... Да и не работают эти скрипты как положено, взять пример выше, информация не нужным образом вставляется в поля почтового клиента, хоть что это будь (Яндекс, Mail? Google, The Bat и т.д)...

Comment: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/custom-php-contact-forms/ + http://www.000webhost.com/free-php-hosting Это найдено за минуту гугления) А народ.ру давно умер.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию... Будем стараться... У меня с английским плохо поэтому я тока на русскоязычных источниках смотрю.. Народ? Ну можно сказать и так, но сделать визитку для себя там вполне можно)

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем ответ на вопрос. Но для отправки почтовой формы со статической страницы, можно воспользоваться сторонними сервисами вроде [этого](http://www.jotform.com/).